# Command to show the db that I'm currently using in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

What is the command to show the current db in the MongoDB shell?

(I failed to find it on Google)

Comment: db.show() doesn't work for me in the shell.

Comment: Just a note: In c# Mongo Driver, you can get current database name via: "_collection.Database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName" command. _collection is IMongoCollection<YouEntity>.

Comment: [Official documentation link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Found it by guessing :)  Simply:

`db`

Comment: nice! That means `use some_db` is just a wrap for  `db = "some_db"` .  And typing a variable in the shell gives the value of the variable.

Comment: technically db is an object - if you need its name as a string then use db.getName()

Comment: "Found it by guessing" :)

Answer (score 57):

The command to get database name in the shell is:

```
> db.getName()
```

While just typing db works, you will find that this only works interactively and if you're working on a script this may not give the result you want.

Comment: if you want db name as a string then yes, getName() is the correct way to get it.  Just db is an object.

Answer (score 2):

`db.current`

is a CLI command that will show you the database you are currently working in

Comment: The response is a little bit weird, e.g. `video.current` for the `video` database.

Comment: Same as `db.bla` will give you `video.bla` for the `video` database. I do not feel that this answer adds anything to the accepted answer.

Comment: The command 'db' is enough. Adding anything after it will output in dbname+input.